# Pass more than one parameter can be used in Html.Action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

how to pass more than one parameter using an Html.Action.

```
@ Html.Action("StringName","ActionName","Controller",new{id=param1,name=param2})
```

Please let me know is this correct format.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: This answer is for `ActionLink`. You can still use the parameters to invoke actions (which are invoked directly when you use `Html.Action`)*

You can just pass them (as you did in the example). All parameters which are not found in the route are used as query string parameters.

You can catch all of them in another action.

Note that all values should be correct C# declarations, so to pass the second parameter as a string you need to use double quotes (as in regular C# code):

```
@Html.Action("StringName","ActionName","Controller",new{id=param1,name="param2"})
```

Comment: Thanks Jgauffin. Should i do any changes in Global.asax.cs to use the above Html.ActionLink()

Comment: Nope. Nothing have to be changed. The querystring is automatically used. You should only make changes if you want the parameter to be used in the path as in `/controller/action/id/name/`, the default behavior is `/controller/action/id?name=xxxx`

Comment: Just a remark: the Html.Action doesn't send any request so there are no query string parameters, but the answer is correct: this is the way to pass multiple parameters to a child action.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Right. I was sure that it said `ActionLink`. I've edited the answer.